# helm install nginx for 404 not found

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I did a helm install of Nginx like this

```
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
--namespace ingress-nginx \
--create-namespace \
--version 4.2.0 \
--set controller.ingressClass=nginx \
--set rbac.create=true \
--values /tmp/ingress-nginx.yaml
```

everythng got deployed fine

```
[rke@k8gui apps]$ kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-248rc   1/1     Running   0          3m15s
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-hpv8h   1/1     Running   0          3m15s
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-jwzjn   1/1     Running   0          3m15s

NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.43.117.177   192.168.33.100   80:31678/TCP,443:32340/TCP   3m4s
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.119.134   <none>           443/TCP                      3m4s

NAME                                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   3         3         3       3            3           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3m4s
[rke@k8gui apps]$ curl http://192.168.33.100
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but curling on the loadbalancer ext ip show 404 not found

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the **404** due to you have maybe not deployed any **ingress**.

The output you have pasted above is the ingress controller which is a **Nginx** **controller** with **external** **IP**. The ingress controller manages the **ingress** or in other words, routing rules.

If you have not created any ingress rules to divert traffic into a cluster or if rules are **not matching** **Nginx** will throw the **404** error.

You are getting the 404 itself from Nginx so when you are hitting the **External IP** of Controller your request reaches till **Nginx** but no rule matches.

**as you see in output**

```
<hr><center>nginx</center>
```

Try creating one hello app deployment and rule of ingress routing as shown in example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: i followed this and I am not able to ge the ingress working. I know the clusterIP and nodeport works because I can curl to it from the host and responds. I also know my metallb work becasue I changed it from cluster IP to loadbalancer and I was able to curl to the LB ip. But ingress is not working and I keep getting 503 error

Comment: if you are getting 503 it means your service is down and 503 might be getting that also from Nginx itself. so your controller is up and running but the backend service is not running so it's throwing the 503 service error

Comment: ok I just reinstalled with nginx-stable   and seems to work now. But I can only curl the dns name. the browser is not bring up the site

Comment: that could be some other reason you can update this question status and post new question with more details like ingress file yaml file you have used browser console and logs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to reach external IP from within your cluster.

Could be this is not possible.

Can you try from browser?
Within cluster you could try to reach your cluster IP 10.43.117.177.

Comment: i get the same thing nginx 404 not found

Comment: Just see Harsh Manvars answers is right there is indeed only the controller.